# Two button calculator part 2

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

A calculator has only 2 buttons. The first multiplies the current value by 2, the second divides it by 3 without a remainder (so 8 becomes 2). Can you use this calculator to reach every positive integer when starting with 1?

Here is a similar question: [Two button calculator](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91114/two-button-calculator)

Comment: The question is if this is a kind of reversed Collatz conjecture or a significantly different thing. In the first case there is no proof yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry that I ignored that comment of yours in the other post.

In fact the answer is "yes": every number can be made.

---

Proof: Note that the number $\alpha = \log_32$ is irrational. This implies that the sequence $(\{ k\alpha\})_{k \geq 0}$ is dense in the interval $[0,1)$, where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part.

Now let $n$ be an integer and consider the interval $[\log_3n, \log_3(n + 1))$. Its image under the map $\{ \cdot \}:\mathbb R \rightarrow [0, 1)$ contains a non-empty open set. Hence there exists infinitely many integers $k\geq0$ such that $\{ k\alpha \}$ lies in the image of that interval.

We take such a $k$ that is sufficiently large, so that $k\alpha \geq \log_3n$. Then there is an integer $m\geq0$ such that $k\alpha - m$ lies in the interval $[\log_3n,\log_3(n + 1))$.

Therefore we get the number $n$ via $\lfloor \frac{2^k}{3^m}\rfloor$.

Comment: Ah cool! I am guessing this doesn't give the minimal number of steps though?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky This is far from the minimal number of steps. For example, this algorithm needs $13$ steps to get $6$. And to get $30$ you need $98$ steps...

Comment: It is actually quite easy to apply this. Start with the value $1$. If the current value is less than the goal value $n$ then double it, and if it is $n+1$ or greater then divide by $3$ (without rounding down). Repeat until you get a value between $n$ and $n+1$. Let $k$ be the number of doublings you needed, and $m$ the number of divisions by $3$. This means that you can get to $n$ by doing $k$ doublings followed by $m$ divisions by $3$ with rounding down.

Answer (score 3):

I started making the numbers progressively by hand. The even numbers are easy to compute. (Twice of another lower number). Odd numbers which are divisible by 3 also make unbroken chains (3>6>12>24>48>96 and 9>18>36>72).

> - $1$
> - 1>$2$
> - 1>2>4>8>16>5>10>$3$
> - 1>2>$4$
> - 1>2>4>8>16>$5$
> - 3>$6$
> - 4>8>16>32>64>21>$7$
> - 4>$8$
> - 7>14>28>$9$
> - 5>$10$
> - 10>20>40>13>26>52>17>34>$11$
> - 6>$12$
> - 10>20>40>$13$
> - 7>$14$
> - ??????
> - 8>$16$
> - 13>26>52>$17$
> - 9>$18$
> - 11>22>44>88>29>58>$19$
> - 10>$20$

Here is how each number upto 20 can be written. Note that I could not find a representation for 15.

Comment: 1>>16>5>>160>53>106>35>70>23>46>15

Comment: @DanielMathias Nice. I wasn't going deep enough to get it.